# Layered viewcontroller for iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, cocoapods

I would like to implement a layered viewcontroller control, where pushed viewcontroller doesn't cover the entire screen but will leave say 20pixela width on the left. If 5 viewcontrollers are pushed and I'm tapping on viewcontroller 2, it should expand, but not remove viewcontroller 3,4 and 5. Only slide them to the right.

The idea comes from the iPad app Trivago and I don't know if they're using an open framework. If not, do you guys have a good idea for implementation? The structure/architecture is fine :-)

If I can create a nice control I will make it public as a cocoapod :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may want to do View Controller Containment instead of using a UINavigationController.

See:  [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

**Update:**

More examples:

[WWDC 2011: Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102)

[iOS Programming Recipe 28: View Controller Containment & Transitioning](http://nscookbook.com/2013/08/ios-programming-recipe-28-view-controller-containment-transitioning/)

Comment: Thanks! Yes that was my thought also (though I said "push". I were the easiest way for me to explain)